# Trying to capture click events on anchor tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following which seems to produce the correct html when viewed with Google Chrome's web developer tools:

```
$("<a />", {
    text: "link text goes here"
}).attr({
    href: "#",
    class: "some_class_name",
    id: "divSlot-" + data.id
}).appendTo("#divSlots");
```

I am trying to add a click event to the  tags:

```
$(".some_class_name").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("hello");
});
```

When I click on the links in a browser, nothing happens, not even errors.

What have I done wrong or missed out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use event delegation based event registration since you are dealing with dynamically added elements.

The [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you used is only a short hand for `$(".some_class_name").click(...)`, to make use of event delegation you need to use a different syntax of `.on()`

```
$(document).on("click", ".some_class_name", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the html output it produces?

At first look nothing seems wrong. You could change your code more efficiently to:

```
$(".some_class_name").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation

```
$("document").on("click",".some_class_name", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping it up in the`$(document).ready(function(){/*code here*/})`?
have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/REFh5/

Answer (score 0):

try following (i just changed data.id and it works fine)

```
$("<a />", {
   text: "link text goes here"
}).attr({
   href: "#",
   class: "some_class_name",
   id: "divSlot-21"
}).appendTo("#divSlots");

$(".some_class_name").on("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert("hello");
});
```

working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SF6pN/

hope it helps.